How to model the impact of cancellations on case resolution times in the legal department considering different stages and contract characteristics?
I'm working on an analysis to understand the case resolution times in my company's legal department. Our processes can experience cancellations that revert to previous stages, affecting the overall resolution time.
Specifically, I want to estimate how much additional time these cancellations add, depending on the stage at which they occur. Additionally, I need to consider variations based on the type of contracts and the requesting department. My initial approach was to use a regression model where the dependent variable is the total resolution time, and the independent variables include cancellations between stages, contract type, and requesting department. To handle the variability in case types, I considered clustering to segment cases into homogeneous groups and then applying the regression model to these clusters.
My questions are:

Is it a good idea to perform clustering before regression for this type of analysis?
Are there other approaches or models that might be more suitable for analyzing the impact of cancellations on resolution times?
How can I validate the effectiveness of the clustering and subsequent regression?

My data includes detailed information about each case, such as the start and end dates of each stage, records of cancellations and the stages in which they occurred, and characteristics of the contract and the requesting department. Any suggestions or recommendations on the best approach for this analysis would be greatly appreciated.
Is there anything else you would like to add or modify?

Since your response variable is a time (and you can call it a "survival", measuring how long a case survives in the legal department before it "dies", that is, is resolved). So maybe survival analysis? If interested in that, maybe add the tag [tag:survival]

This is an interesting problem (to me!).
On the one hand, we seem to have time-to-event data, indicating a survival-type model. On the other hand, it seems that "cases" can move "forward" towards resolution, or backwards to a previous state.
A Markov state-space model might be a good idea in this situation. Markov models are excellent at modeling processes where the next state depends only on the current state (the Markov property). This is particularly useful for modeling case resolutions with potential cancellations that revert to previous stages.
A Markov state space model can incorporate time-dependent transitions, which are important when different stages and cancellations affect the resolution time. These models can handle different types of contracts and departments by adjusting transition probabilities and state definitions. A general approach to this type of modelling is:

Define States

Each stage in the process is a state (eg Initial Review, Drafting, Approval, etc.) and additional states for cancellations and reversion (eg Cancelled to Initial Review, Cancelled to Drafting).

State Transition Matrix:

Construct a matrix where each element represents the probability of transitioning from one state to another. Incorporate transition probabilities for cancellations and reversion to previous stages.

Data Preparation:

Encode the stages and transitions from the historical data. Calculate empirical transition probabilities based on the observed frequencies of transitions between stages.

Modelling

Implement the Markov model using appropriate software (for example, in R the markovchain and msm packages). Use the transition matrix to simulate the case resolution process, considering cancellations and stage reversion.
Other approaches could also be considered: cluster analysis and survival models for example.
